# How to write a SQL query to delete the first element (the very first character) of a path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a column for images which stores the link of images.

The example looks like this:

```
\\Images/image1.jpg
```

Now assume my database has more than 1000 records for 1000 images which is working fine, but now due to some requirement change, I have to update the links.

I want to remove the first slash from the all 1000 records via a SQL query.

Now it is stored like this:

```
\\Images/image1.jpg
```

and I want to convert it to

```
\Images/image1.jpg
```

One approach is to go to 1000 records and remove it one by one, which is too time consuming, as an alternative what could be a SQL query that could be run via SSMS?

Comment: @jarlh MS Sql Server

Comment: You should really add more sample data to make the problem clearer. Like single slash first, another character first, then double/single slash etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` to do this:

```
update yourTable
set yourColumn = replace(yourColumn,'\\','\')
```

Comment: It does not work right for all cases, if there is another two slashes not in the beginning of the path, it will replaced too.

Comment: @HasanGholamali, then see my answer since it avoids exactly that problem

Comment: @JoakimDanielson exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To only update values that start with "\\" you can do

```
UPDATE someTable SET col = REPLACE(col, '\\%', '\')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it on Ms SQL.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(path, 2, LEN(path) - 1) FROM yourtable
```

EDIT:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET path = SUBSTRING(path, 2, LEN(path) - 1)
WHERE SUBSTRING(path, 1, 2) = '\\'
```

Comment: Do i have to write 1000 queries for 1000 records?

Comment: I added a new statement. Run it once on your table, and it should update them all.

Comment: Edit: Thanks Hasan. I forgot that SQL indices start counting at 1. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to fetch your data set like this, then try using RIGHT function in your select query; your query should look something like this;

```
SELECT RIGHT(path, LEN(path)-1) FROM yourtable
```

If you want to update your table with updated values than use the UPDATE query, should look something like this;

```
UPDATE yourtable SET path = RIGHT(path, LEN(path)-1) FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use replace for this purpose!  You want to remove the first slash, and `replace()` replaces all matching values everywhere in the string.

Plus, SQL Server has a very simple function to do this:

```
update t
    set col = stuff(col, 1, 1, '')
    where col like '\\%';
```